# mongodb - All nodes in replica set are primary

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to configure a replica set with two nodes but when I execute `rs.add("node2")` and then `rs.status()` both nodes are set to PRIMARY. Also when I run `rs.status()` on the other node the only node that appears is the local one.

Edit1:
`rs.status()` output:

```
    {
        "set" : "rs0",
        "date" : ISODate("2012-09-22T01:01:12Z"),
        "myState" : 1,
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "name" : "node1:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 1,
                        "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
                        "uptime" : 70968,
                        "optime" : Timestamp(1348207012000, 1),
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2012-09-21T05:56:52Z"),
                        "self" : true
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 1,
                        "name" : "node2:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 1,
                        "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
                        "uptime" : 68660,
                        "optime" : Timestamp(1348205568000, 1),
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2012-09-21T05:32:48Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2012-09-22T01:01:11Z"),
                        "pingMs" : 0
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Edit2: I tried doing the same thing with 3 different nodes and I got the same result (`rs.status()` says I have a replica set with three primary nodes). Is it possible that this problem is caused by some specific configuration of the network?

Comment: You shouldn't create a ReplicaSet with an even number of nodes. If you have space concerns, add an arbiter node (which has no storage but gets to vote for primary) as third.

Comment: Could you update your question with the output of `rs.status()`?  Make  sure to make the output anonymous before posting.

Comment: already updated it. Sorry for the late response

Comment: What happens when you insert a document?  Does it write to both, or error out?  What happens if you add an arbiter to your replica set?

Comment: I inserted documents to both primaries and there was no error but they didn't synchronize . I also added an arbiter to the replica set from the first node and it was successful but nothing happened (both nodes still appear to be "primaries"). Is there any way to delete completely replica set configurations so I can start over?

Comment: Could you open a community private issue on this at the [MongoDB Jira](https://jira.mongodb.org/)?  This will allow you to post logs in a way removed from public viewing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you issue `rs.initiate()` from both of your the members of the replica set before `rs.add()` then both will come up as primary.

You should only use `rs.initiate()` on one of the members of the replica set, the one that you intend to be primary initially.  Then you can `rs.add()` the other member to the replica set.

Comment: I just realized this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The answer above does not answer how to fix it. I kind of got it done using trial and error.

I have cleaned up the data directory (as in `rm -rf *`) and restarted these PRIMARY nodes, except one. I added them back. It seems to work.

**Edit1**
The nice little trick below did not seem to work for me,

---

So, I logged into the `mongod` console using `mongo  <hostname>:27018`

here is how the shell looks like:

```
rs2:PRIMARY> rs.conf()
{
    "_id" : "rs2",
    "version" : 1,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "host" : "ip-10-159-42-911:27018"
        }
    ]
}
```

I decided to change it to secondary. So,

```
rs2:PRIMARY> var c = {
...   "_id" : "rs2",
...   "version" : 1,
...   "members" : [
...     {
...       "_id" : 1,
...       "host" : "ip-10-159-42-911:27018",
...       "priority": 0.5
...     }
...   ]
... }

rs2:PRIMARY> rs.reconfig(c, { "force": true})
Mon Nov 11 19:46:39.244 DBClientCursor::init call() failed
Mon Nov 11 19:46:39.245 trying reconnect to ip-10-159-42-911:27018
Mon Nov 11 19:46:39.245 reconnect ip-10-159-42-911:27018 ok
reconnected to server after rs command (which is normal)

rs2:SECONDARY>
```

Now it is secondary. I do not know if there is a better way. But this seems to work.

HTH